# How to fix intermittent/jerky android paint updates

Tags: android, graphics, invalidation, rate

(I tried to stuff the question with keywords in case someone else has this issue - I couldn't find much help.)

I have a custom View in Android that contains an LED bargraph that displays levels received via socket communication. It's basically just a clipped image. The higher the level, the less clipped the image is.

When I update the level and then invalidate the View, some devices seem to "collect" multiple updates and render them in chunks. The screen visibly hesitates for say 1/10th of a second, then rapidly paints multiple frames, and then hesitates again. It looks like it's overwhelmed and dropping frames.

However, when changing another UI control on the screen, the LED bargraph paints much more frequently and smoothly. I'm thinking Android is trying to help me by "collecting" multiple invalidations and then doing them all at once. Perhaps by manipulating controls, I'm "increasing" my frame rate simply by giving it "more to do" so it delays less between actual paints.

Unlike animation (with smooth transitions) I want to show the absolute latest value as quickly as possible. My data samples aren't faster than 10-20fps anyway.

Is there an easy way to "force" a paint at certain points, or is this a limit of how Views work? Should I be implementing this in a SurfaceView instead? (I have not played with that yet... want advice first.) Thanks in advance for suggestions.

*(Later that same day...)*

Update: I found a page in the Docs that does suggest implementing my widget as a SurfaceView is the way to go:

http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/graphics/2d-graphics.html

*(An hour after that...)*

SurfaceView seems overkill for what I want to do. The best-practice method is to "own" the whole canvas, but I have already developed the rest of my controls and layouts and they work well. It must be possible to get *some* better performance with what I have, especially since interacting with the UI makes the redraw speed satisfactory.

Answer (score 0):

It turns out `SurfaceView` was the way to go. I was benchmarking on an older phone which didn't help. (The frame rate using a standard `View` was fine on an ASUS eeePad). I had to throw away some code, but the end result is smoother and faster with `SurfaceView`. Further, I was able to re-use more code than I expected and actually dramatically simplified my multitouch handling code (since everything I want to touch is in the same `SurfaceView.`

FYI: I'm still only getting about 15fps on Droid X, but half of the CPU load appears to be data packet processing. The eeePad is doing almost 40fps now -- and my data rate is only 20 samples/sec.

So... a win I guess. I want the Droid X to run better, but it flies on a real tablet.